# the meaning of expression on and on

Tags: word-usage

What is the meaning of the epression 'on and on'?
The expression 'on and on' have the same meaning like the expression 'again and again'?

Comment: Slightly different but the same basic idea.  A long song might go "on and on" even though it doesn't repeat.

Comment: so 'on and on' mean rather  continously and 'again and again'mean rather repeatedly?

Comment: the meaning is continually or continously or that depend on the context?conntinually imply the recurence,something that is repeating with intermittency and continously is something uninterupted

Comment: Continuously is "on and on".  Continually is "again and again".  (Though don't take any of this too literally -- the terms are often applied rather loosely.)

Comment: i  understand that often this terms are  interchangeables becouse they are not rigorous defined, more precisely, it is not taken into account in practice about the way they are defined logically

Comment: becouse i saw in differents dictionaries both the meaning continually and continously for the expression 'on and on'...